Are there other ways to express $W_0(Ax\exp{x})$?
I'm working on a physics problem where the Lambert W function arises. I get very close to being able to cancel it, as its argument is almost its inverse function, but not quite.
The term I end up with is $$W_0\left(Ax\exp{x}\right),$$ where choosing the principal branch is required/justified because $x$ and $A$ are each both real and positive. I've been using Iacono and Boyd's algorithm  for computing $W_0$.
I'm motivated to ask whether there are other ways of expressing this term for two reasons: -

$x$ is sometimes large enough that $\exp{x}$ cannot be represented in 64 bit float format, or small enough that $\exp{x}$ is below machine precision and thus gets treated as 0, which is out of the domain of Iacono and Boyd's algorithm. I can get around this by using a modified version of the algorithm, but this is peicewise and thus slows down my computation (I need to do many evaluations).
$Ax\exp{x}$ is so close in form to $x\exp{x}$, that I am curious to know if there is any way of expressing the overall term more simply which eliminates the Lambert W function and exponential. For example, as $xf(A)$ or $f(x,A)$ where $f$ is some fancy hypergeometric function or something. I'm aware that making the equation more terse in this way would likely come at the cost of computation time, so is in tension with motivation 1.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated!

Thanks for your response. I've played around with that transformation before and didn't get anywhere, but I'll give it another go. It does feel like it could be the solution - I'll let you know.

a)
$$W(Axe^x)=y$$
Can calculation of $x$ from given $y$ help?
$$Axe^x=W^{-1}(y)$$
$$Axe^x=ye^y$$
$$x=W\left(\frac{ye^y}{A}\right)$$
b)
Some references for example:
Corless, R. M.; Gonnet, G. H.; Hare, D. E. G.; Jeffrey, D. J.; Knuth, D. E.: On the Lambert W Function. Adv. Comput. Math. 5 (1996) 325-359
Corless, R. M.; Jeffrey, D. J.; Knuth, D. E.: A sequence of series for the Lambert W function. In: ISSAC '97: Proceedings of the 1997 international symposium on Symbolic and algebraic computation, July 1997, 197-204.
Johansson, F.: Computing the Lambert W function in arbitrary-precision complex interval arithmetic. 2017
Corcino, R. B.; Corcino, C. B.; Mezo, I.; Ontolan, J. M.; Gasparin, R. J.; Malusay, J. T.; Rosell, J. P.; Kiunisala, E. M.; Elnar, A. R. B.; Galon, C. M. V.: Numerical calculation of the real r-Lambert function. J. Inequal. Special Func. 10 (2019) (3) 44-49

Thanks for your reply and the references. Unfortunately $y$ isn't known, but I'll give a closer reading to the reference talking about the r-Lambert W function, as some more exotic version of the function may be what I'm after.

By definition, $W_0\left(Ax\exp{x}\right)$ is equal to a number $w$ such that $we^w = Axe^x$.  Taking logarithms,
$$\ln w + w = \ln A + \ln x + x$$
If $A = 1$, then $w = x$ satisfies the equation.  Otherwise, I don't think there's a more convenient closed-form expression, but taking the logarithm may be useful for calculating $w$ numerically.  Try using a fixed-point iteration on
$$w = \ln A + \ln x + x - \ln w$$
import math

MAX_ITERATIONS = 100

def solve_w(A, x):
    w = x
    for _ in range(MAX_ITERATIONS):
        old_w = w
        w = math.log(A) + math.log(x) + x - math.log(w)
        if w == old_w:
            break
    return w
```


This answer shows a way to write $\ln(W(A xe^x))$, which still contains $W(A x e^x)$

Thanks for your response, it looks like this may be an alternative route around the problem with the size of $\exp{x}$ I've been having, and it may use fewer $\ln$ evaluations than Iacono and Boyd's algorithm depending on how many iterations are needed. I'll do a comparison when I return to work on Monday.
